# How to get the content of 2 lists into 1 tuple

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have

```
l1 = [1,2,3,4]
```

and

```
l2 = [5,6,7,8]
```

Having that how can I create this tuple `([1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8])`?
The `tuple()` function only works with 1 argument at max

Comment: Why not just `(l1, l2)` ?

Comment: `my_tuple = l1, l2`

Answer (score 1):

Consider using surrounding parentheses for clarity:

```
>>> l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> l2 = [5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> (l1, l2)
([1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8])
```

However, they are not required:

```
>>> l1, l2
>>> ([1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8])
```